# Solving a system of implicit functions

Tags: systems-of-equations, implicit-function

I am trying to separate $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ in the given system:

\begin{equation}
     \begin{array}{cc}
          xu+yv=x+y  \\
          yu-xv=x-y 
     \end{array}
 \end{equation}

However, when I arrange as matrix and solve for the determinants I get

$$\begin{vmatrix}
xu & yv\\
yu & -xv
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
x & y\\
x & -y
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$\begin{equation}
    uv= \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}
\end{equation}$$

But still, here I cannot separate $u$ and $v$. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: While using the matrix method, you don't just find determinants; there is something else as well. Anyways, for this case, I'd rather recommend using a substitution or an elimination.

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $x$ and the second by $y$, then you get $$
 \begin{align*}
          x^2u+xyv &= x^2+xy  \\
          y^2u-xyv &= x^2-xy 
 \end{align*}$$
Now just add both equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the top equation by $y$ to get $xyu+y^2v=xy+y^2$, multiply the bottom by $x$ to get $xyu-x^2v=x^2-xy$. Subtract to get
$$
v=\frac{-x^2+2xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\ .
$$
Proceed similarly.

Comment: Thanks! So is the matrix method not advised here?

Comment: @vqngs The "matrix method" works here, but you need to use it properly. You are supposed to form the matrix with the **coefficients** of the system, not with the whole terms.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix approach is to write the system as a linear system and use Cramer's rule:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y\\ y & -x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ v
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x + y\\
x  -y
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here is another take, with complex numbers.

Let $z=u-iv$. Then $(x+iy)z=(x+y)+i(x-y)$ and it's easy to solve for $z$.

Comment: Thanks, I cant give thumbs up, because I have no credit. But I would give if I had!

Comment: Perhaps I will give it on the above user's behalf then.